# How do I use Data.Constraint to reify constraints?

Tags: haskell

I have a function of type

```
(forall m. (MonadCo r m, MonadReader Int m) => m ())
    -> (forall m. (MonadCo r m, MonadReader Int m) => m ())
```

(`MonadCo` is my own typeclass representing a coroutine monad.  If you like you could consider the case `MonadError e m` instead.  The question will be identical.)

It seems like I should be able to reify the constraint and end up with a function with type signature like

```
(Equals k (MonadCo r, MonadReader Int))
    => (Constrain k ()) -> (Constrain k ())
```

but I have no idea how to go about implementing this in practice.  I am completely baffled as to what `:-` and `:=>` actually are.  I suppose I also need a `Forall1` in there somewhere, because I'm universally quantifying over `m`, but I don't see where it should fit.

Really what I want to do is reify the `forall m. (MonadCo r m, MonadReader Int m)` constraint.  I presume that when I do that, whatever ends up appearing on the left hand side will automatically be "the right thing".

`Data.Constraint` seems very powerful, but I can't work out where to start.

Comment: That's certainly possible. And you don't need scary things like `:-` or `Forall1`.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem possible. Looks like your "Implies" would be contravariant in k, while the function you want won't be.

I mean, what if you have some bizarre class `MonadFoo m`, and you define

```
type k m = (MonadCo r m, MonadReader Int m, MonadFoo m)
```

Suppose that this class is specifically designed in such a way that there could be only one instance of this class (well, if you don't use `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` at least), some monad `MMM`, which is also an instance of `MonadCo r` and `MonadReader Int` . Then your type `Constrain k ()` would likely be isomorphic to just `MMM ()`. So, you want a function `MMM () -> MMM ()` — but the input type, `MMM ()` is so much weaker than what you need for your function to work. It's unlikely you'd be able to generalize your function in this way.

**UPDATE:**

Some happy Oleg'ing, and we have the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
module Forall where
import Control.Monad.Reader
class Monad m => MonadCo r m where
scary ::
    (forall m. (MonadCo r m, MonadReader Int m) => m ()) ->
    (forall m. (MonadCo r m, MonadReader Int m) => m ())
scary = undefined -- here goes your original function
class Equals (d1 :: (* -> *) -> *) d2 where
    equals :: p d2 -> p d1
    default equals :: p d1 -> p d1
    equals = id
data Dict k (m :: * -> *) where Dict :: k m => Dict k m
type Constraint d a = forall m. d m -> m a
data (d1 :+: d2) (m :: * -> *) = Plus (d1 m) (d2 m)
newtype ConstraintTrans d = ConstraintTrans {runCT :: Constraint d () -> Constraint d ()}
warmAndFuzzy ::
    forall r d.
    Equals d (Dict (MonadCo r) :+: Dict (MonadReader Int)) =>
    Constraint d () -> Constraint d ()
warmAndFuzzy =
    let scary' ::
            (MonadCo r m, MonadReader Int m)
            => (forall m'. (MonadCo r m', MonadReader Int m') => m' ())
                -> m ()
        scary' = scary
        waf :: Constraint (Dict (MonadCo r) :+: Dict (MonadReader Int)) () ->
               Constraint (Dict (MonadCo r) :+: Dict (MonadReader Int)) ()
        waf c (Plus Dict Dict) =
            let arg :: forall m'. (MonadCo r m', MonadReader Int m') => m' ()
                arg = c $ Plus Dict Dict
            in scary' arg
    in runCT $ equals $ ConstraintTrans waf
```

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean about contravariance.  I'll edit the question to make it less impossible.  But really I'm not asking a precise question.  Instead I'm asking how to reify the constraint and my example was really just my latest confused thought about what it should look like.

Comment: Wow.  I now actually think your original comment about contravariance was the key point for me, and made me realise what I was originally trying to achieve is probably impossible.  So thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should be a good start:

```
type ReaderAndCo r m = (MonadCo r m, MonadReader Int m)

g :: (forall m . Dict (ReaderAndCo r m) -> m ())
  -> (forall m . Dict (ReaderAndCo r m) -> m ())
g x Dict = f (x Dict)
```

You can further split the dictionary for `ReaderAndCo` into two components if you
wish.

To make it more similar to the code in your question, you can introduce an additional synonym:

```
type Constrain k a = forall m . Dict (k m) -> m a

g :: Constrain (ReaderAndCo r) () -> Constrain (ReaderAndCo r) ()
g x Dict = f (x Dict)
```

Is this what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: We can also add `class Equals k1 k2 where equals :: p k1 -> p k2` (with some type signatures).

Comment: I think it's made me realise that the end result I'm trying to achieve is actually impossible, which is pretty much as useful, so thanks!